# Creating a structure from a C++ function prototype

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Suppose one has a C++ function `foo` with the following prototype:

`bool foo (int a, double x, const std::vector<std::string>& v);`

Is it possible via meta-programming to automagically create a struct type whose attributes are the input arguments of the function ? For this example, one would get a structure equivalent to:

```
struct 
{
    int arg1; 
    double arg2; 
    std::vector<std::string> arg3;
};
```

I guess that it is possible to achieve this through techniques like those introduced by A.Alexandrescu in "Modern C++ Design", but I was wondering whether such a 'prototype2struct' feature already exists in some library.

To add a little more context, I get the `foo` function from outside and its prototype can be anything. The underlying idea is to encapsulate a call to `foo` in order to execute it on another computer. Which means that I need:

1. to serialize the arguments of the call in a buffer
2. to send them on the remote computer
3. to execute the call on the remote computer.

So my idea was to create a type from the function prototype a use some serialization library on this type.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?  What is wrong with your approach of expliticly writing down the struct? And then passing that struct by reference to foo? (I often do this in a dependency injection environment) since it can facilitate maintainability. But other then that just be as explicit as you can (just pass arguments explicitly or model a struct explicitly)

Comment: I think what I am trying to say is "don't try to outsmart yourself to safe up on a few lines of code"

Comment: Are you looking for `std::bind`? It creates a callable structure with member variables that are copies of bound function arguments.

Comment: You could use [`boost::function_traits`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html) and then find a way to get a `std::tuple` of the argument types out of it, which shouldn't be too hard. But this won't work for function templates or overloaded functions. Also you won't be able to generate new structs through template meta programming.

Comment: Lambda functions exactly do that.

Comment: @chrysante, yes I am actually working torwards such a solution and I guess I will manage to find one; but I was looking for a potentially existing solution, better coded than I could do in the first place.

Comment: "its prototype can be anything" doesn't looks reasonable. and you cannot really get a type that can be anything.

Comment: @apple apple, you're right, "anything" is surely excessive in my context. At least, simple types like those I put in the example could be enough for me.

Comment: @edrezen Well, the hard part is really getting the `function_traits` template right. Boost does that part for you. Copying the types into a tuple should be straight forward from there.

Comment: @chrysante No need to use `boost::function_traits`. This can be done using CTAD as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76366825/12002570).

Comment: Typically people define a protocol, like a protobuf service (see interface definition/description language, aka IDL) to define remote procedure calls. Wanting o call "any" function looks like a red flag at least for C++.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `std::tuple` and CTAD as shown below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <tuple> 
bool foo (int a, double x, const std::vector<std::string>& v);

template<typename Ret, typename... Param> struct GetParamType
{
   using type = std::tuple<Param...>;
   public:
       GetParamType(Ret(*)(Param...)); 
};

struct Name
{
    decltype(GetParamType(foo))::type t;   //std::tuple of desired types   
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/43GfGo3dz)

---

Do note that this won't work for overloaded functions.

Comment: You can also leverage `std::function` with CTAD to cover more then function pointers.

Comment: @super Yeah, I wanted to show the most minimal and readable version that shows what OP posted in the question. This can be modified as you said, to cover more cases.

Comment: I would like to see you implement support for functors though without all the ugliness of my solution. Because you have to create so many specializations for all the reference/const/noexcept qualifier combinations afaik.

Comment: @chrysante Yes I originally wrote/used this to circumvent exactly that. In particular, the specializations that are needed for different cases can be at least minimized through this. Though it can be somewhat tricky/difficult/ugly(not impossible though ofcousre) here to modify this for functors.

Comment: @chrysante Since `std::function` already deals with all the wierd stuff [this](https://godbolt.org/z/rEThv4eKW) becomes a pretty neat solution.

Comment: I see no reason to use CTAD here, just normal template deduction would work.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not pretty, but here it goes: (Then again is TMP ever pretty?)

```
template <typename F>
struct argument_tuple {
private:
    using FT = function_traits<F>;
    static constexpr size_t arity = FT::arity;  
    template <size_t... I>
    static auto get_tuple(std::index_sequence<I...>) -> std::tuple<typename FT::template argument<I>...>;
public:
    using type = decltype(get_tuple(std::make_index_sequence<FT::arity>{}));
};
```

This of course relies on a `function_traits` meta function. I found that `boost::function_traits` is not enough here, because it doesn't let you access argument types by index.

[Here is a live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nYdPv8aE7)

Please test this implementation more thoroughly than I did before you use it for anything serious.

Comment: Looks pretty ugly but at least it works. Also check out more readable [version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76366825/12002570)

Comment: Ages ago I found a similar implementation somewhere on SO, from which this implementation is derived. Unfortunately I can't seem to find it again. Also this version is heavily edited by me and probably won't resemble the original post very much, but if you find it please let me know.

Comment: Sure, someday somewhere we will find it(hopefully), lol.

Comment: @Jason Well, it's not really the same because this also works for function objects with user defined `operator()`

Comment: I see though I'm sure if OP were to say that they also want this to work with functors then my version can be modified accordingly. But since OP didn't explicitly say that and shown an example with only ordinary function, I am going to say that they are not looking for functors solutions. But good to have solution that works with functors.

Comment: @Jason I will heavy heartedly admit that your solution is pretty smart and perhaps superior to mine.

Comment: I was looking for a name to call this trick/idiom. I've been using this at many places and wrote this as an alternative to specializations that were used to solve a particular problem one time I was reviewing some code. Perhaps you could suggest some name for this trick/idiom. I think this could have a separate name as just CTAD doesn't completely describe the trick. Would be nice to have a separate name and see this trick used at more places.

Comment: Check this:https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/callable_traits/doc/html/callable_traits/reference.html#callable_traits.reference.ref_args . You already have the arguments as a tuple with boost.calkable_traits.

Answer (score 0):

A naive implementation considering only free(static or none-member) functions would be:

```
template<typename>
struct arguments
{ using type = void; };

template<typename R, typename ... args>
struct arguments<R(args ...)>
{using type = std::tuple<args...>; };

template<typename F>
using arguments_t = typename arguments<T>::type;
```

But that excludes C variadic functions & abominable functions, as well as function pointers, member function pointers, function objects and lambdas. Calling conventions - not being std - are another problem.

One attempt to tackle this problem was [**boost.callable_traits**](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/callable_traits/doc/html/index.html). But that too ommits calling conventions and is too complicated, yet better than boost.function_traits relying on MPL.

Comment: My own (free, production grade, fully documented) solution at https://github.com/HexadigmSystems/FunctionTraits handles 
everything you mentioned including calling conventions (the only such solution out there that does to the best of my knowledge). The only thing it doesn't handle is abominable functions by design (few will be impacted by its absence but consult the above link for details). The solution is otherwise more complete than all others I'm aware of including Boost's  .

Comment: Did you notice the boost link? There are 3 different boost libraries, trying to implement this; and none of them omits abominable functions. How does your impedimentation stack up against them?

Comment: I omitted abominable functions by design since very few will ever require them in practice. The reasons are fully explained at the above link and their absence won't be a show stopper for most (few will ever need it). As for how it compares to Boost, it's more complete IMHO and the main issues are discussed at the link itself. Note that I've also examined the Boost code and it's needlessly complicated and bloated IMHO (so many files for a relatively small though non-trivial task). My own solution effectively does everything it does and more. It's a very worthy (humbly better) competitor.

Comment: If it works for you, then good for you. But if you want to publish it, it has a long way to go. As I mentioned in a previous comment boost provides 3 different libraries for the matter. I just linked one in my post. Now you can think why std has no such Library? The answer is simple: No satisfying generic library with simple enough implementation exists. standard doesn't miss corner cases ; implementations of standard don't miss their special extensions.

Comment: It was never intended to be published in Boost or elsewhere and wouldn't make it into the C++ standard itself. Its support for calling conventions alone would disqualify it (since they're not supported in the standard), let alone no support for abominable functions. The issues are addressed in the link itself in its "design considerations" section. As a practical function traits library however, for everyday use by most developers, I believe it has certain benefits that give it an edge over all other solutions I've seen, including its lone support for calling conventions (an important one).